# Objective-C/Cocoa equivalent of fread

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

I'm trying to read in the first four bytes of a file. I know that this works correctly with the following C code:

```
FILE *file = fopen(URL.path.UTF8String, "rb");
uint data;
fread(&data, 4, 1, file);
NSLog(@"%u", data);
```

This prints out: 205

I'm trying to find the equivalent way of doing this in Objective-C/with Cocoa functions. I've tried a number of things. I feel like the following is close:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:URL error:nil];
NSData *data2 = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:4];
NSLog(@"%@", data2);
NSLog(@"%u", (uint)data2.bytes);
```

This prints out: < cd000000 >

and: 1703552

As expected, the first four bytes of the file are indeed CD000000.

I'm assuming there's one of two things causing the difference (or both):

1. fread is not counting the 0s following the CD. I've confirmed this by only reading in 1 byte with the fileHandle, but sometimes this number will extend greater than one byte, so I can't restrict it like this. Do I need to manually check that the bytes coming in aren't 00?
2. This has something to do with endianness. I have tried a number of functions such as CFSwapInt32BigToHost but have not been able to get back the right value. It would be great if anyone can enlighten me as to how endianness works/effects this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not dereferencing the data.

```
NSLog(@"%u", (uint)data2.bytes); // wrong
```

The "quick hack" version is like this:

```
NSLog(@"%u", *(uint *) data2.bytes); // hack
```

A more robust solution requires copying to a variable somewhere, to get the alignment right, but this doesn't matter on all platforms:

```
uint value;
[data getBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)];
NSLog(@"%u", value);
```

Another solution is to explicitly read the data byte-by-byte, which is most portable, has no alignment issues on any platform, and has no byte-order issues on any platform:

```
unsigned char *p = data.bytes;
uint value = (unsigned) p[0] | ((unsigned) p[1] << 8) |
             ((unsigned) p[2] << 16) | ((unsigned) p[3] << 24);
NSLog(@"%u", value);
```

As you can see, there are good reasons why we avoid putting binary data in files ourselves, and leave it to libraries or use text formats.

This can't be an issue with byte order, because `fread()` is working correctly.  The `fread()` function and the `-readDataOfLength:` method will both give you the same result: a chunk of bytes.

Comment: (Equivalent) alternative to memcpy: `[data getBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)]`.

Comment: Your "portable" code example should consider the size of type `uint`. Otherwise, it explains the subtle issues thoroughly.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: The "portable" solution is for portably reading a 4-byte integer, **not** for portably reading a `uint`.  It is portable, because `uint` is guaranteed to be at least 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You attempt reinterpret a sequence of 4 bytes as an unsigned int. This is not guaranteed to work on all platforms. It will only work if sizeof(unsigned int) equals 4. And it will only work if the byte order is the same for reading and writing.

Furthermore, you are not printing the scalars correctly with NSLog.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yes, that too, in the second part of the sample when using the `bytes` property.  ;)  (I was referring to the first part of the sample where an uint is filled with 4 bytes)

Answer (score -1):

`fread()` in binary mode won't do anything to your data, you'll get the bytes as they are in the file.

It's absolutely byte ordering that is causing this, but I don't know anything about Apple's Objective C API:s. I don't understand why you don't need to do pointer accesses to the `data2` object, even (why isn't `data2.bytes` failing, and `data2->bytes` needed?).

Also, the documentation for `NSData` doesn't say anything about byte order that I could find.

Comment: `data2.bytes` is Objective-C syntax for attribute access.

Comment: `data2.bytes` is for accessing a property of an object; `data2->bytes` would access an instance variable (think structure member), if and only if you have access to that instance variable (ivars are protected by default, so you could only access that ivar if you were in an NSData implementation). The property access syntax is equivalent to a message expression (method call): `data2.bytes` == `[data2 bytes]`.